# Why is my array still NULL

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to create a simple way to lay out tiles for a game.

How ever I am new to java and OOP, for some reason my the variables in my array are still null after I assigned variables to them via a loop.

What have I done wrong, why is my array still NULL? Thanks.

```
        stages stage1 = new stages();

    public void stage1init() {
        stage1.stageW = 30;
        stage1.stageH = 30;
        stage1.tileSize = 100; 
        stage1.stageStartX = 2;
        stage1.stageStartY = 24;
        //Layout Stage1
        int W = stage1.stageH;
        int H = stage1.stageW;
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                stage1.TilePositionX[i][j] = 100 * j;
                stage1.TilePositionY[i][j] = 100 * j;
            }
        }
    }


    //Draw current stage

    public void drawStage1() {
        int W = stage1.stageH;
        int H = stage1.stageW;
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                saveCurrentTransform();
                translate(stage1.TilePositionX[i][j], stage1.TilePositionY[i][j]);
                drawImage(grasstile, 0, 0, 100, 100);
                restoreLastTransform();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need more code to actually reproduce your problem ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: post your stages class.

Comment: You are not setting them anywhere in this code. Can you show us where you are creating the arrays?

Comment: they are created in stages.java `public class stages {
    int stageW;
    int tileSize;
    int stageH;
    int stageStartX;
    int stageStartY;
    double[][] TilePositionX;
    double[][] TilePositionY; `

Comment: Use [edit] option to provide more informations in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, I needed to assign the size of the array.

```
public void stage1init() {
        stage1.stageW = 30;
        stage1.stageH = 30;
        stage1.tileSize = 100; 
        stage1.stageStartX = 2;
        stage1.stageStartY = 24;
        stage1.TilePositionX = new double[stage1.stageW][stage1.stageH];
        stage1.TilePositionY = new double[stage1.stageW][stage1.stageH];
        //Layout Stage1
        int W = stage1.stageH;
        int H = stage1.stageW;
        for(int i = 0; i < H; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                stage1.TilePositionX[i][j] = 100 * j;
                //EDIT: For anyone looking to do something simular, multipy the following by i not j;
                stage1.TilePositionY[i][j] = 100 * i;
            }
        }
    }
```